# Problems with converting the DateTime input

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm new to OOP, and are writing a Tennis Tournament program, where the players have the following data (I made the Person class a superclass, because I later need to connect a referee class with some of the same instance variables). When I try to create a new player in my SVM method, I cannot create, because I get an error with the birthdate input. When I try to input 1981/09/26 it says: "Argument 4: cannot convert from 'int' to System.DateTime'.

What can I do to fix this? The other inputs like string and the GenderType works fine?

```
public class Person
{
    public enum GenderType     { Male, Female}
    private string FName       { get; set; }
    private string MName       { get; set; }
    private string LName       { get; set; }
    private DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    private string Nationality { get; set; }
    private GenderType Gender  { get; set; }

    public Person(string fn, string mn, string ln, DateTime bd, string nation, GenderType g)
    {
        FName = fn;
        MName = mn;
        LName = ln;
        Birthdate = bd;
        Nationality = nation;
        Gender = g;
    }

    public override string ToString(){ return "Firstname: " + FName + " Middlename: " + MName + " Lastname: " + LName + " Birthdate: " + Birthdate + " Nationality " + Nationality + " Gender: " + Gender;}}

public class Player : Person {

public Player(string fn, string mn, string ln, DateTime bd, string nation, GenderType g) : base(fn, mn, ln, bd, nation, g)
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1 = new Player("Serena", "J.", "Williams", 1981 / 09 / 26, "USA", GenderType.Female);
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a string when creating a new Player instead of a DateTime?

Comment: You have to call «new DateTime(...)» and pass the year/month/day of your date's to each argument.

Comment: this 1981 / 09 / 26 is not correct. You must write new DateTime.Parse("1981/09/26") instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are not passing a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) type instance, instead you are passing literal directly which compiler is considering as of type `int` but it is clear from your code you have `Birthdate` property in your class of type `DateTime`.

You need to create a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) type object :

```
new Player("Serena", "J.", "Williams",new DateTime(1981,09,26),"USA", GenderType.Female);
```

The first parameter is year, 2nd is month and 3rd is day of month in the `DateTime` constructor.

Following is the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) being used for it.

Answer (score 0):

var p1 = new Player("Serena", "J.", "Williams", new Datetime(1981,09,26), "USA", GenderType.Female);

Answer (score 0):

You can set date time like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p1 = new Player("Serena", "J.", "Williams", new DateTime (1981, 09, 26, 0, 0, 0), "USA", GenderType.Female);
}
```